# "datastore: internal error: server returned the wrong number of entities" when retrieving non-existent object

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

With the go API for Google App Engine I try to retrieve a non-existent object:

```
func entityKey(c appengine.Context, name string) *datastore.Key {
    collectionKey := datastore.NewKey(c, "EntityCollection", "default_entitycollection", 0, nil)
    return datastore.NewKey(c, "Entity", name, 0, collectionKey)
}

//.....

var record EntityRecord // Some random type

key := entityKey(context, "This key does not exist")

err := datastore.Get(context, key, &record)
```

It returns the error:

```
datastore: internal error: server returned the wrong number of entities
```

Whereas I expect the much more obvious `ErrNoSuchEntity`. What gives?

This is on the local development server.

Answer (score 1):

The error is from [here](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/appengine/datastore/datastore.go#273). Given the `internal error` bit this sounds like a bug to me. Reading the code it seems like it should return a slice with one `GetResponse_Entity` with a `nil` `Entity` field, but it's either returning too many `GetResponse_Entity`s or none.

You could tinker with the source code in:

```
go_appengine\goroot\src\pkg\appengine\datastore\datastore.go
```

Add some `fmt.Println`s to this part:

```
req := &pb.GetRequest{
    Key: multiKeyToProto(c.FullyQualifiedAppID(), key),
}
res := &pb.GetResponse{}
if err := c.Call("datastore_v3", "Get", req, res, nil); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Or perhaps try debugging with GDB. (though I'm not sure how you debug an app engine app)

You could also try clearing your local data store with:

```
dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore=yes myapp
```

But that's just a shot in the dark.

You might have better luck asking on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine-go).